# Updatable full outer join in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know Full joins don't exists in MS Access and have to be emulated. I know how to do that with unions, but I need it to also be updatable. 
Apparently a union precludes the query from being modifiable. How do I work around this?

I am helping a user who is reasonably proficient in Access by providing an abstraction that they use for their own queries. 
They are knowledgable enough to write and use their own queries. All I do is provide them a view to abstract away a few internal details. That view needs to be modifiable so the queries they build on top of it are and for business reasons it needs a full join.

Thus I cannot use Forms or VB, it needs to be something I can stick into the view definition. 
What are my options?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  `FULL JOIN` is almost never needed, so I'm surprised that you think it is necessary.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use a temporary table - select necessary data first to temp table, then update the working table using temp table